# Function signature using closures does not appear correctly from other classes

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have created a class called `VerifyObject`, that contains a function with the following signature

```
typealias handlerCodeID = (String) ->Void
typealias handlerCode = (Date, Code) ->Void
typealias handlerError = (NSError) ->Void


func verifyObject(withID:String?,
  runOnEnter: handlerCode?,
  runOnExit: handlerCode?,
  runOnPause: handlerCodeID?,
  runOnError: handlerError?)
```

When I try to use this method from another class using

VerifyObject.verifyObject...

autocomplete shows me this:

> verifyObject(self: VerifyObject)

??????????

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need to call the function on an instance of `VerifyObject` instead of the type `VerifyObject`.

```
let object = VerifyObject() // or whatever input arguments the initialiser takes
object.verifyObject(withID: "id", runOnEnter: ...)
```

Comment: DUUUUHHH, obviously. The point here is that I forgot the word `class` in front of `func`. That was meant to be a class function. THANKS A LOT!